issue emerges inputting vector into a homebrew Clojure function
I am very new to Clojure and I have a simple issue to resolve, which Googling didn't help with. Just as an exercise in learning how to create functions in Clojure, I tried to make a function which takes the values of a vector and calculates their arithmetic mean, in the following manner:
(defn mean [vec]
(   let [x (reduce + vec), y (count vec)] 
    (x / y)
))

When I run this in my interpreter after creating a vector of name vec_foo by typing (mean vec_foo), I get the following message:

Execution error (ClassCastException) at user/mean (REPL:1).
class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.IFn (java.lang.Long is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; clojure.lang.IFn is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

When trying (apply mean vec_foo), the following message appears instead:

Execution error (ArityException) at user/eval369 (REPL:1).
Wrong number of args (5) passed to: user/mean

My initial goal was to just get the average of the vectors values as an output, but these error messages are also very interesting. Any information on either the error messages' meaning, or solving the problem, will be appreciated.

In clojure, you call a function by putting it as the first element in the list, you want (/ x y) instead of (x / y). The error arises because x is not a function (the error message indicates it's a Long, which is not the kind of thing you can call). hth

@Harold Thanks. Looks like I just need to get the hang of the syntax.

I disagree with the close vote. This isn't a typo like accidentally mis-spelling a function name, it's a misunderstanding of Clojure syntax. It is a typical beginner mistake, and so I would happily close it as a duplicate, to help other beginners searching for solutions to the same mistake, except I can't find an exact duplicate. If you do, please vote to close for that reason.

@AshleyBenStory also embrace the parentheses :). You seem to try to imitate curly bracket languages, but it's confusing in this case since Clojure's not one. Look at other Clojure code how the parentheses are structured. Clojure modes in editors will help to keep them balanced. Check out How to Read Clojure Code Like an Expert.

@user2609980 An astute observation- I'm used to using C++ and figured Clojure would teach me to widen my perspective on coding. Thanks for the link, I will check it out.

In your code, x is always a Long
When you run (x / y), it tries to invoke x as a function, but you can't cast a Long to a function.
What you are trying to do is (/ x y)
About sum, as you didn't share the implementation, I can only guess: probably (sum vec_foo) works.

That was a typing error on my part: by "sum", I meant "mean." I have since corrected this. Thanks for pointing it out.
